# change the url of easyui datagrid on button click

Tags: jquery-easyui

i'm using [easyui datagrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php)

i added a new button which would populate the datagrid with another set of data based on what row you selected.

here is the button:

```
a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="view-breakdown()">View Breakdown</a>
```

and this is my table:

```
<table id="dg" title="My Users" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:980px;height:370px;"
        url="get_users.php"
        toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
        rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true" height="auto";>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th field="item_group_desc" width="50">item description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

i want the function view_breakdown() to get the value of item_group_desc and change the url of the table to "breakdown.php"
how can i do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
view_breakdown()
{
   $('#dg').datagrid({
      url:'breakdown.php'});
 }
```